# Create a column in data frame by merging another data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

This is my Data Frame 1 df1:

```
    ID    Date
0   90  02/01/2021
1   101 01/31/2021
2   30  12/31/2021
```

My Data frame 2 df2:

```
    ID  01/01/2021  02/01/2021  12/01/2021
0   90    20           14          22
1   101   15           10          5
2   30    12           9           13
```

In df1, I need to create a column 'Attendance'. It should contain the data of nearest date column available in df2 with respect to 'Date' column in df1 for an 'ID'.

Nearest Dates according to 'Date' of df1:

02/01/2021 --> 02/01/2021

01/31/2021 --> 02/01/2021

12/31/2021 --> 01/01/2022 ,if not available consider latest date column of df2.

I am finding difficult in merging the data. How could I do it? Is it possible to  achieve it without creating any extra columns?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    dict(ID=90, Date=datetime.date(2021, 2, 1)),
    dict(ID=101, Date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 31)),
    dict(ID=30, Date=datetime.date(2021, 12, 31)),
])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'ID': 90, '01/01/2022': 20, '02/01/2021': 14, '12/01/2021': 22},
    {'ID': 101, '01/01/2022': 15, '02/01/2021': 10, '12/01/2021': 5},
    {'ID': 30, '01/01/2022': 12, '02/01/2021': 9, '12/01/2021': 13},
])

df2_melted = pd.melt(df2, ['ID'], var_name='Date', value_name='val')
df2_melted['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2_melted['Date']).dt.date


df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2_melted, on='ID')
df_merged['time_diff'] = (df_merged['Date_y'] - df_merged['Date_x']).dt.days

date_after_mask = df_merged['Date_y'] >= df_merged['Date_x']


dfg = df_merged.groupby('ID')['time_diff']

df_merged['min_diff'] = dfg.transform('min')
df_merged['max_diff'] = dfg.transform('max')
min_is_neg = df_merged['min_diff'] < 0
df_merged['min_diff'] = df_merged.min_diff.mask(min_is_neg, df_merged.max_diff)

valid_rows = df_merged['time_diff'] == df_merged['min_diff']
df_out = df_merged[valid_rows][['ID', 'Date_x', 'val']]
df_out.columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'Val']
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ID        Date  Val
1   90  2021-02-01   14
4  101  2021-01-31   10
6   30  2021-12-31   12
```